# Using list to do mathematics in python

Tags: python-2.7

Lets say I got:

```
my_list = [('l', '1'), ('l1', '2'), ('l', '1'), ('l', '4')]
```

I want to add all elements, divide it by 2, and print the result. I've no idea  how to proceed , even after looking everywhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should look into [list comprehensions/generator comperehensions](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions). This method uses the latter combined with [sum](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sum):

```
l = [('l', '1'), ('l1', '2'), ('l', '1'), ('l', '4')]
print sum(int(x[1]) for x in l)/2. # -> 4.0
```

Comment: thank you  for your help Sir !  will do thanks for the advice also

Answer (score -1):

you can enumerate through a list of tuples and access their second item like this:
(note: in the list of tuples in this code, i am treating the second part of the pair as a number rather than a string or character)

```
sampleList = [('l', 1), ('l1', 2), ('l', 1), ('l', 4)]

totalCount = 0

for listItem in sampleList:
    totalCount = totalCount + listItem[1]

finalResult = totalCount/2
```